# Count number of occurrences of (unknown) string in excel column

Tags: vba, excel, google-apps-script

So I have a spreadsheet in excel like this:

```
| some data | PLA      |   
| some data | MADW     |      
| some data | IBFWE    |      
| some data | RWIUBGER |      
| some data | WIUFBW   |
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of each of these strings and enter it into a new spreadsheet. Kind of like a key value store, with the key as the string and the value as the number of occurrences. It needs to be able to be run a number of times (whenever the spreadsheet has a new entry). How would I accomplish something like this? My spreadsheet is too large (150k entries) to do manually.

I've heard of excel macros or of using a python script to import the sheet and then write out to the same file, or some way to use google sheets and call the function from excel itself?

Comment: is your question about excel-vba or Google-apps-script ? can't be both...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a column right next to it and countIf the contents of the entire column:

```
=COUNTIF(L5:L12,L5)
```

Whatever happens to be in L5, will be counted as many times as it's found in the entire range.  Do that down the entire list.

Once you have that, you can bounce that out to another sheet, and remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up an ADO connection to your sheet and run a query on it like it's a database.

```
Dim query_results as variant
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Dim your_file, strSQL as string

your_file = "enter the full path of your excel file this is assuming is .xls"

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & your_file & ";" & _
"Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"
cn.Open strCon
strSQL = "Select value, count(whatever_you're_counting) from [ExcelSheetName$] group by value"
Set rs = cn.Execute(strSQL)
query_results = rs.GetRows
rs.Close
'Code untested
```

At this point you should be able to loop through the query_results and pull out the values/counts and put them in another sheet.